# iPhone: NSDate convert GMT to local time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, localization, nsdate

I currently have an API call returning me a date/time in the format: `2010-10-10T07:54:01.878926`

Can I assume this is GMT? I also converted this to an NSDate object. Is there a way to use the local iPhone time to recalculate the time?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm";

NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
NSString *timeStamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Comment: How does this convert GMT to local time? I believe it's doing the opposite and converting local to GMT right?

Comment: Good example, but it converting from Local Time to GTM.

Answer (score 23):

This code will convert the GMT time to the device's local time.

```c
NSDate* localDateTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:[[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMT] sinceDate:pubDate];
```

Comment: **Swift** : `let localDate = NSDate(timeInterval: NSTimeInterval(NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone().secondsFromGMT), sinceDate: date)`

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDate *sourceDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:gmtTimestamp];
NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:0];
NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;
NSDate* destinationDate = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:sourceDate] autorelease];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm";
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:destinationTimeZone];
NSString *localTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:destinationDate];
```

Answer (score -2):

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"%@", [now dateWithCalendarFormat:@"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" 
              timeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]]);
```

Comment: The message `-(NSString *)dateWithCalendarFormat:timezone:` does not exist in Apple's documentation.