# Local Time Zone iPhone

Tags: iphone, locale, nstimezone

I'm parsing an.ics file that includes time stamps of events like this:

```
20101008T230000Z
```

This is, as far as I understand, expressed in UTC.
Now, I want my app to display  this time correctly, depending on the time zone where the iPhone user resides. So, as an example, if the user would be in London, the time would be displayed as '23:00' while in Amsterdam it would be '22:00'

I've been looking at similar questions here at STackOverflow, and it only confused me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this answer not clear enough? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081647/how-to-convert-time-to-the-timezone-of-the-iphone-device/1082179#1082179

Comment: It shouldn't display 23:00 in London, as London is in BST at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901474/iphone-nsdate-convert-gmt-to-local-time) helps. Read the time into an `NSString` and use the complementary function in `NSDateFormatter` (`dateFromString`) after setting the time zone as shown in the link. You should then be able to get a local date/time from the `NSDate` object's `description` and `descriptionWithLocale` functions.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you very much, and my apologies that I didn't come across this myself.