# Whats the right date format for?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I've been trying to get the `NSDateFormatter` class to format a string which has this format `2015-08-21T21:19:45.328965000000Z`.

The format I use is `yyyy-MM-dd’T’HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSSSSZ`. However the `NSDateFormatter` keeps returning nil as the result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I asked the similar question 3 years back. Please check this answer. Hope this will work.

[How to convert UTC date string to local time (systemTimeZone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677520/how-to-convert-utc-date-string-to-local-time-systemtimezone)

Comment: That doesn't work in my case. The api I'm using returns pico seconds which aren't parsed correctly