# How to convert UTC date string to local time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I currently get time as UTC and I want it to be convert into local time zone 
         `NSDate * startDate;`

Example strDate -  14/9/2017 7.28 Am

Required format - 14/9/2017 1.52 pm

I need help with objective c.

NSDate * startDate ;  //contain utc date

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM d, yyyy - h:mm a"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
 NSString *timestamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:startDate];
```

but this is not correct time but date is correct

Comment: Add your piece of code to show what have you done so far ?

Comment: `NSDateFormatter` is the tool you are looking for.

Comment: What have you tried? Where's the code you've written? Please have a read of [Ask]

Comment: This May help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677520/how-to-convert-utc-date-string-to-local-time-systemtimezone

Answer (score 0):

First convert NSString to NSDate.

```
 NSDateFormatter *DateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 NSTimeZone *timeZoneEDT =[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
 [DateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
 [DateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZoneEDT];
 [DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
 NSDate *CurrentDate = [DateFormatter dateFromString:DateStr];
```

Then convert GMT time to local time.

```
NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Kolkata"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:sourceTimeZone];
NSString *dateRepresentation = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
```

Answer (score 0):

@athira try this. it works for me.

```
    NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/M/yyyy h.mm a"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    NSString *timestamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:startDate];
    NSLog(@"date = %@",timestamp); //date = 14/9/2017 4.34 PM
```

it will print current time with proper GMT+5:30 and i have used localTimeZone.