# NSDateFormatter: how to convert date string with 'GMT' to local NSDate?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to convert a date string retrieved from a server, to local NSDate, the string looks like:

```
"Fri, 30 Nov 2012 00:35:18 GMT"
```

But now it is Friday, 30th Nov, 11:36 AM, so how do I convert the string to a meaningful local NSDate?

I found:

[iPhone: NSDate convert GMT to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901474/iphone-nsdate-convert-gmt-to-local-time)

But looks like it does the opposite.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Note that NSDate's always store the date, internally, in GMT.  You then use a date formatter to create a string in your local time zone.  In this case, you are starting with a string so need to use the date formatter to create the date in the first place, and then use it again to create a string in your local time zone (which it defaults to when the timezone is not specified).

```
NSString *dateString           = @"Fri, 30 Nov 2012 00:35:18 GMT";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.dateFormat       = @"EEE, dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";

NSDate *date                   = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSString *localDateString      = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"%@", localDateString);
// Results:  Thu, 29 11 2012 19:35:18 EST
```

Comment: Oops; I had the wrong zeds in my answer. +1. Though you should still set the locale explicitly — otherwise `NSDateFormatter` reserves the right to modify your exact formatting string.

Comment: @Tommy: If I'm not mistaken, the locale defaults to your current locale.  I just NSLog'd dateFormatter.locale.localeIdentifier (without setting it) and it gave me "en_US", which is my current locale.  That's why I didn't set it, because he wanted it in his local timezone.

Comment: @lnafziger locale and timezone are to independent properties. Using the locale `en_US_POSIX` is important when working with fixed format date/time strings. Without it, it's possible the format will be changed behind your back based on things like the user's 24-hour setting (as one example). Setting the locale has no effect on the format's time zone. See the QA1480 that @Tommy referenced in his answer.

Comment: @rmaddy:  I don't understand the point that you are trying to make.  The locale on a date formatter that I create defaults to `en_US`.  If I am going to display this string to a user, I **want** it to respect the users 24-hour setting, as well as anything else that is specified.  When I am converting **from** a date format (as in this example) the date format specifies the format to expect and it shouldn't matter what the user has specified in his preferences....  Am I misunderstanding something here??

Comment: @lnafziger if you need an exact format you need to set the en_US_POSIX locale. When creating a user format that adapts to various settings then you leave the default locale.

Comment: @rmaddy: Okay, that's what I thought and why I didn't set a locale here.  You guys were just trying your best to confuse me, lol!

Comment: Thanks a lot! The question which has been linked in the question should be corrected. It does local to GMT as opposed to GMT to local.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `NSDateFormatter` with the formatting string `eee, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz`. The Zs at the end cause it to read the time zone from the string.

So, given [QA1480](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html), sample code:

```
NSLocale *usLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setLocale:usLocale];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"eee, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
_createdAt = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: In the link in my question, he used `NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];` why do you not need this?

Comment: You don't need that because your string specifies GMT in it and the `zzz` component of the date format you've set will tell `NSDateFormatter` to use what your string specifies rather than whatever it considers the norm to be.