# How to convert a date string in one format into another format?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert `Tue, 04 Mar 2014 12:45:00 GMT` string of date into `MMMM dd,yyyy` format but in device iOS 6 crash the code and date not convert into required format.

i am trying to do this way.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'Z'"];
NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:date];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd,yyyy"];
return [formatter stringFromDate:date1];
```

any one can help me?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637298/nsdateformatter-how-to-convert-date-string-with-gmt-to-local-nsdate

Comment: BTW - whenever you post a question about an error or crash, you must include full details about the error message and the crash.

Comment: @SurenderRathore i am trying this code it's working same as my code in simulator but it's crash in device.

Comment: try to use zzz in place of 'Z'

Comment: @SurenderRathore , i got ans using this NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]; thank you for your help