# iphone time conversion gmt to local time

Tags: iphone, ios

Am getting the time format like below

"Wed, 12 Dec 2012 09:08:30 GMT" Now i want to convert it to local time format.Please give me your suggestion

Thanks,

Vijayan.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: NSDate convert GMT to local time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901474/iphone-nsdate-convert-gmt-to-local-time)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

LOCAL TO GMT

```
NSString *dateString = @"Wed, 12 Dec 2012 09:08:30 GMT";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MM yyyy hh:mma"];
NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"BST"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:sourceTimeZone];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Answer (score 2):

Well we need to start by creating a `NSDate` object form 'Wed, 12 Dec 2012 09:08:30 GMT'

```
NSString *dateString = @"Wed, 12 Dec 2012 09:08:30 GMT";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EN"]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

You might a spot that I've set the locale on the `NSDateFormatter` this has to do with the localized date (Both the month and day are in english).

Now you can use the date formatter to display the dat in the locale timezone:

```
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSString *localDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```